# Why WinBeacon cannot receive data from etimote beacons

Tags: ibeacon, estimote

I am using an Lenovo Ultrabook with Windows 8.1 OS and Bluetooth 4.0 BLE.

I installed [WinBeacon](https://github.com/huysentruitw/win-beacon) on my notebook by using NuGet Console. I replaced the Bluetooth driver with the WinUSB driver by using the Zadig tool. Then I downloaded the WinBeacon sample project and I started the program. Using this program I was able to send beacon messages but I couldn't receive any message from other beacon devices.

Do I have to pair my PC with the estimote device?

Comment: Hello, pretty late, but today I did an update to the library which should fix this issue.